# How to change QLineEdit font size using QSS?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, font-size, qtstylesheets

The code below creates a single `QLineEdit()` with QSS stylesheet applied.
I would appreciate if you show how to change the font size and font color of the `QLineEdit` using QSS. I have tried `font-size: 12;`. But it doesn't work.

[image]

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

app=QApplication([])

bgColor='#262626'
style="""QLineEdit{{ color: #EBEBEB; border: 0px solid black; background-color: {0}; color: #EBEBEB }} QLineEdit:hover{{ border: 1px solid #ffa02f;}}""".format(bgColor) 

lineEdit=QLineEdit()
lineEdit.setText('My Line Edit')
lineEdit.setStyleSheet(style)

lineEdit.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify a font size with a unit; something like `px`, `pt`:

```
font-size: 30px;
```

Comment: Thanks! Right on target!